# Python GDAL/OGR: check lines geometries connectivity

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr

I'm working with shapefiles representing roads, so basically it's stored as (poly)lines.
I need to perform a road connectivity checking. In other words, I want to ensure that roads meant to communicate are really in contact, because I don't wanna see a little gap between my 2 segments of road.
I don't really see how to proceed.
Should I compute the distance from the current line to the closest ones and then look if this distance is under a threshold? Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: What software do you have available to you?  What have you tried so far?  What is the source of the data?  It may be possible that the roads already have good connectivity.

Comment: I only work using Python + GDAL/OGR. No GIS or graphical tools. Working on shapefiles, yes i guess it's already connected, but need to check to ensure that, and find out possible mistakes